# How to destroy CKEditor instance using variable for its name

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

this is how I destroy CKEditor instance:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.Divname.destroy();
```

with Divname being id of the div.

but, how to destroy instance, if I use variable like this:

```
var x = "Divname";
CKEDITOR.instances.x.destroy();
```

It'll give me x is undefined error.

running example:
http://jsfiddle.net/DBbYm/1/
please enable the instance (to attach editor), and then disable the instance (to destroy), and you'll get the error.

Any advice to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In JS you could call members like this

```
var x = "Divname";
CKEDITOR.instances[x].destroy();
```

Comment: can you get multiple instances using for ex CKEDITOR.instances[".ckeditor"] ?

Comment: Even if it's and old question and old answer, Simon get on more point! Thanks!